# How to open a random image from specified folder/directory in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, random

I want my program to open a random image from the folder.

This works:

```
import cv2
import os
import random

capture = cv2.imread(".Images/IMG_3225.JPEG")
```

But when I want to do this random it doesn't work:

```
file = random.choice(os.listdir("./images/"))
capture = cv2.imread(file)
```

I'm getting the following error:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'`

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What is the value of `file`?

Comment: The error says its in `imshow`, not in `imread` - are you sure opening the file is the problem? Could also be that you're trying to show the result which is None because there are files in the directory that are not images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the small mistakes that we usually overlook while working on it. It is mainly because `os.listdir` returns the contents of a folder. When you are using `os.listdir`, it just returns file name. As a result it is running like `capture = cv2.imread("file_name.png")` whereas it should be `capture = cv2.imread("path/file_name.png")`

So when you are working, **try to use the code snippet:**

```
path = './images'
file = random.choice(os.listdir("./images/"))
capture = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,file))
```

This will help you run the code.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `os.listdir` returns the contents of a folder.

Having this folder structure:

```
images/
    - a.png
    - b.png
    - c.png
```

This would be the expected result.

```
>>> os.listdir('images')
['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png']
```

`file` actually contains the name of a file in `images/`, so `cv2.imread` does not find the file because it's looking for it in the wrong place.

You have to pass `cv2.imread` the path to the file:

```
IMAGE_FOLDER = './images'

filename = random.choice(os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER))
path = '%s/%s' % (IMAGE_FOLDER , filename)

capture = cv2.imread(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import cv2
import random


dirs = []
for i in os.listdir("images"):
    if i.endswith(".JPEG"):
        dirs.append(os.path.join("images", i))

pic = random.choice(dirs)

pic_name = pic.split("\\")[-1]
pic = cv2.imread(pic)

cv2.imshow(pic_name, pic)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```