# How can i load an image after selecting it at random from a specific folder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Python and using the Keras libraries ,and i have a folder containing thousands of images. I want to choose a random sample of these images and then load this sample using (load_img) method , but i cannot do that , so i need So I need your help.

This is the code :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOWMV.png)

This is the erroe:
[error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE1yj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a random image from specified folder/directory in Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643335/how-to-open-a-random-image-from-specified-folder-directory-in-python-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the file path isn't exist. Check `train\traincat.11571.jpg` if exist. Perhaps, you should change code like this as your forgot the sep symbol.

```py
image = load_image(r"xxxxx\" + sample); // path is too long, xxxx for short
```

Comment: I tried to write (r"D:\ملفات قديمة\machine learning_hesham_asem_dataset\train1\train\" + sample) , but i have an error : unterminated string literal (detected at line 9)

Comment: It‘s another question, more error message detail about line 9 should be helpful. @AhmadSarairah